# JavaScript Tic Tac Toe game not making player win

Tags: javascript

I have been working on making a JavaScript Tic Tac Toe game. There's a slight problem with it. In theory it feels it might work but it isn't. So, the problem is, while playing the game if somebody wins then I am not able to detect that win. What I have done is made an array for all Tic Tac Toe game cells and and array for all winning pairs. Now I am using a for loop to go through them and see if a winning pair is formed but I isn't working no matter what I do. I will be really glad if checkout https://codepen.io/Dragonsoup/pen/RwoBBaz and find the problem.
Really thankful for you reading my question.
Have a good day!

```js
let turn = 1;

function play() {
   const box = []
   for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      box[i] = document.querySelector('.b' + i).value
   }
   const winPairs = [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8],
      [2, 4, 6]
   ]
   for (i = 0; i < winPairs.length; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
         if (box[winPairs[i][j]] === "X") {
            e++
         }
         if (e === 3) {
            document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "Player X won";
            disableAll();
            winColor(winPairs[i])
         }
      }
   }
   for (i = 0; i < winPairs.length; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
         if (box[winPairs[i][j]] === "O") {
            e++
         }
         if (e === 3) {
            document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "Player O won";
            disableAll();
            winColor(winPairs[i])
         }
      }
   }
   let i;
   for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      if (box[i] === "") {
         break;
      }
   }
   if (i === 9) {
      document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = 'Match Tie'
      for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
         document.querySelector('.b' + i).style.backgroundColor = "#d13232";
      }
   }
}

function disableAll() {
   var cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell")
   cells.forEach((cell) => {
      cell.disabled = true;
   })
}

function winColor(arr) {
   arr.forEach((cell) => {
      document.querySelector('.b'+cell).style.backgroundColor = "#45d132"
   })
}

function restart() {
   for (i = 0; i < 9; i++){
      document.querySelector('.b' + i).value = "";
      document.querySelector('.b' + i).disabled = true;
      document.querySelector('.b' + i).style.backgroundColor = "";
   }
   document.querySelector('#alert').innerHTML = "Start Playing!";
}

function response(cellNum) {
   if (turn === 1) {
      document.querySelector('.b'+cellNum).value = 'X';
      document.querySelector('.b' + cellNum).disabled = true;
      turn = 0;
      document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "Player X Turn"
   }
   else {
      document.querySelector('.b'+cellNum).value = 'O';
      document.querySelector('.b' + cellNum).disabled = true;
      turn = 1;
      document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "Player O Turn"
   }
}
```

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: poppins;
}

body {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   height: 100vh;
}

table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

input{
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   outline: 0;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 80px;
   color: black;
   font-weight: 800;
}
input:hover {
   background-color: lightgray;
}

.b0, .b1, .b2 {
   border-top: none;
}

.b6, .b7, .b8 {
   border-bottom: none;
}

.b0, .b3, .b6 {
   border-left: none;
}

.b2, .b5, .b8 {
   border-right: none;
}

#header {
   font-size: 40px;
   text-shadow: 6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#alert {
   font-size: 30px;
   text-shadow: 6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#restartBtn {
   background-color: #01a4ff;
   border: 0;
   outline: 0;
   height: 60px;
   width: 100px;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: bolder;
   color: white;
   border-radius: 12px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
#restartBtn:hover{
   background-color: #005c8d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
   <script src="index.js"></script>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
</head>
<body>
   
   <table>

      <tr>
         <th colspan="3">
            <h1 id="header">
               Tic Tac Toe
            </h1>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b0" onclick="response('0'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b1" onclick="response('1'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b2" onclick="response('2'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b3" onclick="response('3'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b4" onclick="response('4'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b5" onclick="response('5'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b6" onclick="response('6'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b7" onclick="response('7'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b8" onclick="response('8'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3" id="alert">
            Start Playing!
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3">
            <button id="restartBtn" onclick="restart()">Restart</button>
         </th>
      </tr>

   </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should probably start by fixing the syntax errors that are simple to fix. For instance, you'll never find a winner  base upon a variable `e` - since it was never defined in the first place. Additionally, using `i` as both a counter and as a logical test is likely causing you any number of issues. This is likely complicated because you never scope the counters `i` or `j` with `let`.

Comment: Thanks I fixed a few errors which I didn't notice really. However, I don't think it's working even after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 let turn = 1;
   let playerOne = []
   let playerTwo = []
   const winPairs =  [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
 ];

function play() {
    if (!winPairs.some(pair => {
      if (pair.filter(el => playerOne.includes(el)).length == 3) {
        document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "Player X won";
        disableAll();
        winColor(pair);
        return true;
      } else if (pair.filter(el => playerTwo.includes(el)).length == 3) {
        document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "Player O won";
        disableAll();
        winColor(pair);
        return true;
      }
    })) {
      if (playerOne.length + playerTwo.length == 9 ) {
        document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = 'Match Tie'
      }
    }
}

function disableAll() {
   var cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell")
   cells.forEach((cell) => {
      cell.disabled = true;
   })
}

function winColor(arr) {
   arr.forEach((cell) => {
      document.querySelector('.b'+cell).style.backgroundColor = "#45d132"
   })
}

function restart() {
   for (i = 0; i < 9; i++){
      document.querySelector('.b' + i).value = "";
      document.querySelector('.b' + i).removeAttribute('disabled');
      document.querySelector('.b' + i).style.backgroundColor = "";
   }
   document.querySelector('#alert').innerHTML = "Start Playing!";
   playerOne = []
   playerTwo = []
   
}

function response(cellNum) {
   if (turn === 1) {
      document.querySelector('.b'+cellNum).value = 'X';
      document.querySelector('.b' + cellNum).disabled = true;
      turn = 0;
      document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "Player X Turn"
      playerOne.push(cellNum);
   }
   else {
      document.querySelector('.b'+cellNum).value = 'O';
      document.querySelector('.b' + cellNum).disabled = true;
      turn = 1;
      document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "Player O Turn"
      playerTwo.push(cellNum);
   }
}
```

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: poppins;
}

body {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   height: 100vh;
}

table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

input{
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   outline: 0;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 80px;
   color: black;
   font-weight: 800;
}
input:hover {
   background-color: lightgray;
}

.b0, .b1, .b2 {
   border-top: none;
}

.b6, .b7, .b8 {
   border-bottom: none;
}

.b0, .b3, .b6 {
   border-left: none;
}

.b2, .b5, .b8 {
   border-right: none;
}

#header {
   font-size: 40px;
   text-shadow: 6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#alert {
   font-size: 30px;
   text-shadow: 6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#restartBtn {
   background-color: #01a4ff;
   border: 0;
   outline: 0;
   height: 60px;
   width: 100px;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: bolder;
   color: white;
   border-radius: 12px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
#restartBtn:hover{
   background-color: #005c8d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
   <script src="index.js"></script>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
</head>
<body>
   
   <table>

      <tr>
         <th colspan="3">
            <h1 id="header">
               Tic Tac Toe
            </h1>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b0" onclick="response(0); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b1" onclick="response(1); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b2" onclick="response(2); play();" readonly>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b3" onclick="response(3); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b4" onclick="response(4); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b5" onclick="response(5); play();" readonly>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b6" onclick="response(6); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b7" onclick="response(7); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b8" onclick="response(8); play();" readonly>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3" id="alert">
            Start Playing!
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3">
            <button id="restartBtn" onclick="restart()">Restart</button>
         </th>
      </tr>

   </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if (winPairs.includes(playerOne.sort().join(","))) {

if you check like this, player has to take winning move only on third attempt. later he can't win. This will lead to Tie.

Comment: Yes.. I missed it.. will fix it

Answer (score 1):

May be this is not the best solution, but for now seems working fine with less effort.

```js
let turn = 1;

function play() {
    const winPairs = [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8],
      [2, 4, 6]
   ];

    const allEle = document.querySelectorAll("input.cell");
    //Getting all values into an array
    const filledValues = Array.prototype.map.call(allEle, ele => ele.value);
    let isAnyPlayerWon = false;

    for(const pair of winPairs) {
      const firstIndValue = filledValues[pair[0]];
      //checking all indexes in pair are filled and has same value or not to find the winning pair
      if (firstIndValue && pair.every(pos => filledValues[pos] === firstIndValue)) {
        document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = `Player ${firstIndValue} won`;
        isAnyPlayerWon = true;
        highlightWinningPair(allEle, pair);
        // break the loop for further checks if we already found the winner
        break;
      }
    }
    
    // checking for Tie, if no play won and every box has value
    if (!isAnyPlayerWon && filledValues.every(value => value)) {
        document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = 'Match Tie';
        disableAll(allEle);
    }
}

function highlightWinningPair(allEle, wonPair) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(allEle, (ele, index) => {
        if (wonPair.includes(index)) {
          ele.style.color = "#008000";
        }
        ele.disabled = true;
    });
}

function disableAll(allEle) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(allEle, ele => {
        ele.style.backgroundColor = "#d13232"
        ele.disabled = true;
    });
}

function winColor(arr) {
    arr.forEach((cell) => {
        document.querySelector('.b' + cell).style.backgroundColor = "#45d132"
    })
}

function restart() {
    const allEle = document.querySelectorAll("input.cell");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(allEle, ele => {
        ele.value = "";
        ele.disabled = false;
        ele.style.color = "";
        ele.style.backgroundColor = "";
    });
    document.querySelector('#alert').innerHTML = "Start Playing!";
}

function response(cellNum) {
    if (turn === 1) {
        document.querySelector('.b' + cellNum).value = 'X';
        document.querySelector('.b' + cellNum).disabled = true;
        turn = 0;
        document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "Player O Turn"
    } else {
        document.querySelector('.b' + cellNum).value = 'O';
        document.querySelector('.b' + cellNum).disabled = true;
        turn = 1;
        document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "Player X Turn"
    }
}
```

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: poppins;
}

body {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   height: 100vh;
}

table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

input{
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   outline: 0;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 80px;
   color: black;
   font-weight: 800;
}
input:hover:not(:disabled) {
   background-color: lightgray;
}

.b0, .b1, .b2 {
   border-top: none;
}

.b6, .b7, .b8 {
   border-bottom: none;
}

.b0, .b3, .b6 {
   border-left: none;
}

.b2, .b5, .b8 {
   border-right: none;
}

#header {
   font-size: 40px;
   text-shadow: 6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#alert {
   font-size: 30px;
   text-shadow: 6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#restartBtn {
   background-color: #01a4ff;
   border: 0;
   outline: 0;
   height: 60px;
   width: 100px;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: bolder;
   color: white;
   border-radius: 12px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
#restartBtn:hover{
   background-color: #005c8d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
   <script src="index.js"></script>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
</head>
<body>
   
   <table>

      <tr>
         <th colspan="3">
            <h1 id="header">
               Tic Tac Toe
            </h1>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b0" onclick="response('0'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b1" onclick="response('1'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b2" onclick="response('2'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b3" onclick="response('3'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b4" onclick="response('4'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b5" onclick="response('5'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b6" onclick="response('6'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b7" onclick="response('7'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b8" onclick="response('8'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3" id="alert">
            Start Playing!
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3">
            <button id="restartBtn" onclick="restart()">Restart</button>
         </th>
      </tr>

   </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Umm. I am just a beginner I would love an explanation of this I don't quite understand what you have written please comments in your javascript thanks!

Comment: Updated refactored code, now it's far better and simple too. hope you'll understand it now. :)

Comment: Nice game! That was a lot of fun! :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let turn = 1;

let e=0;
function play() {
   
   const box = []
   for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      box[i] = document.querySelector('.b' + i).value
   }
   const winPairs = [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8],
      [2, 4, 6]
   ]
   for ( let i = 0; i < winPairs.length-1 ; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
         if (box[winPairs[i][j]] === "X") {
            e++
         }
         if (e === 3) {
            document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "Player X won";
            disableAll();
            winColor(winPairs[i])
         }
      }
    e = 0; //made e to zero for checking new condition
   }
   for (let i = 0; i < winPairs.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
         if (box[winPairs[i][j]] === "O") {
            e++
         }
         if (e === 3) {
            document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "Player O won";
            disableAll();
            winColor(winPairs[i])
         }
      }
    e =0; //made e to zero for checking new condition
   }
   
   for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      if (box[i] === "") {
         break;
      }
   }
   if (i === 9) {
      document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = 'Match Tie'
      for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
         document.querySelector('.b' + i).style.backgroundColor = "#d13232";
      }
   }
}

function disableAll() {
   var cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell")
   cells.forEach((cell) => {
      cell.disabled = true;
   })
}

function winColor(arr) {
   arr.forEach((cell) => {
      document.querySelector('.b'+cell).style.backgroundColor = "#45d132"
   })
}

function restart() {
   for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
      document.querySelector('.b' + i).value = "";
      document.querySelector('.b' + i).disabled = true;
      document.querySelector('.b' + i).style.backgroundColor = "";
   }
   document.querySelector('#alert').innerHTML = "Start Playing!";
}

function response(cellNum) {
   if (turn === 1) {
      document.querySelector('.b'+cellNum).value = 'X';
      document.querySelector('.b' + cellNum).disabled = true;
      turn = 0;
      document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "Player O Turn"
   }
   else {
      document.querySelector('.b'+cellNum).value = 'O';
      document.querySelector('.b' + cellNum).disabled = true;
      turn = 1;
      document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "Player X Turn"
   }
}
```

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: poppins;
}

body {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   height: 100vh;
}

table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

input{
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   outline: 0;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 80px;
   color: black;
   font-weight: 800;
}
input:hover {
   background-color: lightgray;
}

.b0, .b1, .b2 {
   border-top: none;
}

.b6, .b7, .b8 {
   border-bottom: none;
}

.b0, .b3, .b6 {
   border-left: none;
}

.b2, .b5, .b8 {
   border-right: none;
}

#header {
   font-size: 40px;
   text-shadow: 6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#alert {
   font-size: 30px;
   text-shadow: 6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#restartBtn {
   background-color: #01a4ff;
   border: 0;
   outline: 0;
   height: 60px;
   width: 100px;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: bolder;
   color: white;
   border-radius: 12px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
#restartBtn:hover{
   background-color: #005c8d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
   <script src="index.js"></script>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
</head>
<body>
   
   <table>

      <tr>
         <th colspan="3">
            <h1 id="header">
               Tic Tac Toe
            </h1>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b0" onclick="response('0'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b1" onclick="response('1'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b2" onclick="response('2'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b3" onclick="response('3'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b4" onclick="response('4'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b5" onclick="response('5'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b6" onclick="response('6'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b7" onclick="response('7'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
         <th>
            <input type="text" class="cell b8" onclick="response('8'); play();" readonly>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3" id="alert">
            Start Playing!
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3">
            <button id="restartBtn" onclick="restart()">Restart</button>
         </th>
      </tr>

   </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To run the game successfully you need to make value of variable e = 0 after every outer for loop iteration.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: @corsaro Actually I missed to add solution while posting the code. So I have commented below what have to done so the code will work. As my understanding, The value of variable 'e' needs to make zero after every iteration of outer 'for loop' i.e. "e = 0" then code will work. I hope this is sufficient. for ex.                
    e = 0; //made e to zero for checking new condition